# How to translate whole html page in another language in Django?

Tags: html, django

Currently I am developing website using Django framework & I have to translate my web page into another language (French) & all other pages are in English language.

```
<html lang="fr">
```

I have set like above but code not working & getting page in English language only.

Comment: The HTML lang attribute is used to declare the language of a web page or just a part of a web page. It is used to help search engines and browsers.https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-language-codes.html

Comment: If only it were this easy! Setting the lang attribute on the HTML tag does not change the language of the page, it only declares to browsers and search engines, "Hey, this content is in the following language." You'll need to manually translate you website. 

For reference on how to do translation in Django, check this:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Add a `LOCALE_PATHS` var in your settings.py. For example:

```
USE_I18N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
)
```

2) change your main `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns 
    urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',

      ...
    )
```

3) in your templates add

`{% load i18n %}`

and `{% trans 'Lorem ipsum ...' %}`

4) now you can run

`python manage.py makemessages`

open 'locale/fr/django.po' and translate all sentences you need.

Don't forget to 
`python manage.py compilemessages`